# print NullPointerException of not found file

Tags: java, file

How can I print `NullPointerException` if the file is not found?
I want to show a message using `JOptionPane` but it did not work.

I tried the following :

```
public void readTextFile()  {
    FileInputStream fs = null;

    try {
        URL file2 = getClass().getResource("/ReadWriteFile/Student.txt");
        String file_path=file2.getPath();
        file_path=file_path.replaceFirst("/","");
        File file = new File(file_path);
        fs = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));

        try {
            String line = reader.readLine();

            while(line != null){    
                System.out.println("line=="+line);    
                line = reader.readLine();
            }   
        } 

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    } 

    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The file you trying to reach is not found");
        Logger.getLogger(Read_WriteToFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
```

Comment: If the file is not found, `fs = new FileInputStream(file)` throws a `FileNotFoundException`. If you get a `NullPointerException`, it's for some other reason.

Comment: What happens in your code now? Do you get a NullPointerException (and where)? Do you want to catch one? Instead or in addtion to the FileNotFoundException?

Comment: You should improve your code formatting.  If you are using an IDE like Eclipse, hitting `CTRL-SHIFT-F` will format for you and it will look niiiiiice.  :)

Comment: Thanks @oleq, the code look much better now.

Comment: @Thilo , can you look for the editted code 
NullPointerException appears in the line
" String file_path=file2.getPath();"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {

...

} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();

}
```

It will print all exceptions including `RunTimeException` s like `NullPointerException`